# Is "haha" a sarcastic phrase?

Tags: meaning, popular-refrains

So, is that "fake" funny? Is there any difference beetween "hehe", "haha", "huh", "heh", "hahaha", "ha", and so on and so forth?

Comment: *Haha* is **not** a "phrase." Haha!

Comment: Are you asking about the onomatopoeic words or the utterances?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I saw them in forums, YouTube comments, and so on.

Comment: Only when said sarcastically.

Comment: @HotLicks Good call.

Comment: By the way, Ha-Ha Wall: *The name "ha-ha" derives from the unexpected (i.e., amusing) moment of discovery when, on approach, the recessed wall suddenly becomes visible.* (Wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ha-ha)

Comment: "**1.** haha = I’m acknowledging that you’ve said something you perceive to be funny, though I don’t find it particularly funny myself. **2.** haha. = I am weary and loathe to laugh, but here, you have forced it upon me; OR: I hate you. **3.** haha! = I am pleasantly surprised to learn you are capable of modest humor." (*The 42 Ways To Type Laughter, Defined* Katie Heaney, buzzfeed http://www.buzzfeed.com/katieheaney/the-42-ways-to-type-laughter-defined#.mbKnjW0n1)

Comment: This question is not POB--[nobody cares whether *you* think it's sarcastic](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6603/nobody-cares-how-you-pronounce-it). Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(AmE)
(I assume you mean sounds actually pronounced, rather than sound of genuine laughter, or written.)

Title question: Yes.

Sarcastic? Yes (if said in response to someone else's remark)

Fake funny? Yes, or "just kidding" (if said after one's own remark)

"hehe" - not common, but same as haha

"haha" - see above

" huh" - usually "huh?" means I didn't hear you, or didn't hear you clearly. . what did you SAY?

"heh" - not common, I would take it llike "eh?" as in what did you mean?

"hahaha" - like haha , only more sarcastic, especially if slow

"ha" (usually "hah!")  - not even funny, just I don't believe it.

Comment: Source(s)? Or is that an informed opinion?

Comment: Mere opinion. Feel free to quote sources, or share your differing experiences. I'm sure there's room for a lot of nuance in these.

Comment: We can use "comments" for opinions.

Comment: Ad comments are for opinions: I would use "tehee" for a somewhat witchy, mischievous giggle. Also, "teheheee"

Comment: What if I'll write "haha" at the end of my own sentence? Will it genuine laughter?

Comment: There is nothing sarcastic about *haha.* It is a way to represent laughter in writing. We laugh for many reasons.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I pefaced my answer so as to limit it to spoken "haha", not actual laughter. Edited it to clarify I don't mean written either. Except when I mentioned "tehee", which was not responsive to the question. I'll take that part out.

Comment: If you said something you think is funny, you don't need to add your own laughter to the message.  If you are writing email or texting, and say something that you don't mean seriously, try ending with (LOL). If repeating a joke you thought was very funny, try ROFL or LMAO (look these up if you don't know them).

Comment: _Heh_ is not like _eh?_ at all. It's not a question, it just represents a quick chuckle that's not long enough to be an actual laugh.

Comment: Indeed. And "heh, heh, heh, heh", said with the right intonation, is a villainous, malevolent chuckle.

Answer (score 3):

Context, intonation and facial expression are more important than the written form of these utterances.

Answer (score 2):

"huh", "heh" are more indicators of surprise. Such as when as when you realise that some money has been deducted from your bank statement: you may make a sound "huh"?

And "ha" is when you catch someone out. "Ha, so it's you who took my pen!!"

But all the others are just laughter. Nothing fake about them, and no sarcasm at all.